# Проблема с header

Tags: php

Выдает ошибку - Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\localhost\www\index.php:1) in Z:\home\localhost\www\index.php on line 1

```
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$db_database = 'newster';
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password);
if(!db_server) die("Don`t connect is mysql" . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_database) or die("Don`t select DB " . mysql_error());

header ('Location: views/index.html');
```

Comment: А что до этого куска? php говорит, что header уже послан, и сейчас идёт тело ответа.

Может какое-нибудь echo затесалось. Или ещё какая зараза.

Comment: Оффтоп: "Don`t connect is MySQL" и "Don`t select DB" убили :)

Comment: @void Как Вас легко убить. Тут по русски пишут так, что без переводчика намаешься разбирать, а Вы про аглицкий язык...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF8 without bom